# Only desktop wallpaper is showing on booting?

Tags: xubuntu

I updated my grub by removing nomodeset.

When I restarted my pc it showed only wallpaper.

I updated my grub again by adding nomodeset. It did not made any difference.

My terminal is not working I had to use ctrl - alt -f4 for cmd line operations.

My system is ubuntu 20.04 .

Comment: It is common to give All relevant information when asking a question. This includes code or commands that you have used that 1)got you into trouble and/or 2)code and commands that you did to remedy the issue. For example, How exactly did you modify your grub?

Comment: Also, the `nomodeset` option is commonly used to force GRUB to use fallback graphics drivers (typically used only when no proprietary GPU drivers are installed yet) and should not be left enabled unless you have a good reason to do so. Did you blacklist the fallback graphics modules (`nouveau` for NVIDIA and `radeon` for AMD) after installing proprietary drivers?

Comment: I don't know but is it possible that the problem came because I interrupted the "sudo apt update" routine ?

Comment: I removed the nomodeset to solve the problem of displaying ubuntu screen to tv. It did not solved it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an actual solution, but a workaround I'm using is patience... I have found that if I wait several minutes after the login screen appears before logging in, it works.
Obviously, if you're not even getting the login prompt, this isn't apropos. Sorry I've got nothing else.

Comment: Thanks. But I solved the problem by "rm -r ~/.config"